# Populating IceFaces HtmlSelectOneListbox when not using xhtml

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I am implementing comboboxes in an application where IceFaces forms are being built dynamically. There are no xhtmls around, we put together everything from Java code. This works nice so far, but I am stucked at `HtmlSelectOneListbox`. In my code I create one that appears on the form as well correctly, but I don't know how to add the `SelectItems` to it.

```
HtmlSelectOneListbox combo = new HtmlSelectOneListbox();
combo.setId(id);
combo.setDisabled(readOnlyWindow);

/* parent is the UIComponent instance around us*/
parent.getChildren().add(combo);
```

I can create instances of `SelectItem`s or even `SelectItemsTag` but the combo has no methods to set them. It has only a `setValue`/`setValueExpression` and with that I could set my value binding expression to the object representing `#{bean.value}`. But the selectitems property should be set not on the listbox but its nested `f:selectItems` that I don't know how to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `UISelectItem` and/or `UISelectItems` objects should be added as children of HtmlSelectOneListbox in a similar way you add combo to the parent component.